# Is openldap client 2.4 compatible with openldap server 2.3.43?

Tags: openldap

Recently, I am being instructed to add a machine to the cluster which has openldap server 2.3.43 running on it. However, the client version on the machine is 2.4. After changing the configuration, it has failed to connect with the following error message.

localhost nslcd[26280]: [899b93] failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://*********/: Can't contact LDAP server: Connection timed out

the client is running on CentOS6 while the server is running on CentOS5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a network connectivity problem, not a compatibility problem. Both versions implement the same LDAP protocol.

Comment: But both of the machines have no issue communicating between each other. I am able to ping the server from the client machine.

Comment: That only proves that ICMP works. The issue here is that TCP to the LDAP port on the server doesn't work. That's a network connectivity problem. Not an LDAP versioning problem. If it was an LDAP problem you would get an LDAP error. Read the error message.

Comment: So how can i configure the TCP on the server machine to accept the connection? 

I have also tried to telnet from client machine to the server machine which failed.

Comment: It has nothing to do with TCP on the target machine. Either the target machine has a firewall rule preventing the connection, or you have a connectivity issue further down the line.

Comment: In the end it turns out to be the firewall on router that caused the issue. As the router isn't administrated by us, we had to physically move the affect machines to the same rack.